# What's the point of the "who is eligible to vote" canvass?

Tags: united-kingdom, voter-registration

Every year UK local councils send enquiry forms to residential properties to ask who living at this address is eligible to vote.

What's the point of this?

Comment: Any thoughts on this.  Why does the obvious not satisfy, ie "to find out who living at this address is eligible to vote".

Comment: @JamesK i dont know why they would need to do that

Answer (score 9):

It’s to ensure the Electoral Register is both accurate and complete. Local authorities are obliged to carry out this process under the Representation of the People Act 1983. From [section 9D](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1983/2/section/9D):

> The purpose of the canvass is to ascertain—
>
> - (a) the names and addresses of persons who are entitled to be registered in a register maintained by the officer but who are not
>   registered;
> - (b) those persons who are registered in such a register but who are not entitled to be registered.

This is important because the register is not only used to determine who is eligible to vote, but is also used both by the government as a data source for funding allocation, for example, and also by private companies such as credit brokers.